# Need help: Isomorphism vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

For $a+bi\in\mathbb{R}(i)$, we have that $a+bi=a\times1+b\times i$. Then, if $a+bi=0$, then $a=0=b$. Thus $\{1, i\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}(i)$.

Then the isomorphism $a+bi\to(a, b)$ is what needs to be proven... I am working on making this more detailed because I think I am still being too vague. Could anyone help me out with finishing this out?

Comment: What is your working definition of $\mathbb{R}(i)$?

Comment: @user10354138 the field $\mathbb{R}(i)$ is defined as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Then what is the field $\mathbb{R}(i)$?  *How* do you know elements of $\mathbb{R}(i)$ are in the form $a+bi$?

Answer (score 4):

What you did is fine. And there is really not much left. The map$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbb R(i)&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R^2\\a+bi&\mapsto&(a,b)\end{array}$$is an isomorphism precisely because $a+bi=0\iff a=0\wedge b=0$.

Comment: So in this case, because we have that fact we would not need to prove all of the requirements for an isomorphism explicitly?

Comment: Actually, it should also be proved that it's a linear map, but that's very easy indeed. And surjectivity is obvious.

Comment: With this problem though, proving of the linear map is way different from what I have done in the past with other problems. since we have the $a+bi$, would the right direction be to plug in the new variables to show the equivalences?

Comment: I don't know which equivalences you are talking about here. It is just a matter of noticing that, since $(a+bi)+(c+di)$ is equal to $(a+c)+(b+d)i$, it is mapped to $(a+c,b+d)=(a,b)+(c,d)$. And a similar argument applies to the product by a scalar.

Comment: So then the argument for product would be similar to $(a+bi)(c+di)=(a+c)(b+d)i$ maps to $(ab, cd)=(a, c)(b, d)$... etc.?

Comment: No, since we're talking about **real** vector spaces here and because there is no multiplication in $\mathbb R^2$. What we do here is to observe that, if $\lambda\in\mathbb R$, $\lambda.(a+bi)=(\lambda a)+(\lambda b)i$, which is mapped to $(\lambda a,\lambda b)$, which is equal to $\lambda.(a,b)$.

Answer (score 3):

What you did is to make a **big assumption**: every element of $\mathbb{R}(i)$ can be written as $a+bi$.  This is part of the question -- that $\{1,i\}$ actually spans $\mathbb{R}(i)$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space.

Compared with a similar situtation $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2)$.  Here $\{1,\sqrt[3]2\}$ is not a basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2)$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.  So there is something to prove here.

Comment: Ah- i see. I felt like I was missing a big part. How would I go about proving this part though?

Comment: Prove that $\mathbb{R}1+\mathbb{R}i=\{a+bi\mid a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$ is closed under multiplication and taking inverses of nonzero element.

Comment: I am working on that proof, but in the meantime would it not be enough to do this? Because i is algebraic with degree 2 over $\mathbb{R}$, each element of $\mathbb{R}(i)$ can be expressed in the form of a+bi with $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$ (definition of complex number) so {1, i} is a basis for $\mathbb{R}(i)$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes that will do.

Comment: Sounds good. thank you for all of the help.